# prisma $queryRaw doesn't work with single quotes in the string

Tags: postgresql, orm, prisma, pg

i have a query that goes

```sql
select count(id), status,  "createdAt"::date from "ProjectLog" where "projectId" = (select id from "Project" where slug = ${id}) and "createdAt" > current_date - interval '${interval} day' group by "createdAt"::date, status;
```

i've also tried user `Prisma.sql` to pass the value inside the quotes but it keeps throwing error that it expected 1 argument but fount 2.

i did not have this issue with prisma `2.20.1`
this issue is only happening on version `3.3.0`

```sh
Query: select count(id) as count, status,  "createdAt"::date from "ProjectLog" where "projectId" = (select id from "Project" where slug = $1) and "createdAt" >  current_date - interval '$2 day' and key notnull group by "createdAt"::date, status
Param: ["main","30"]
PrismaClientKnownRequestError:
Invalid `prisma.queryRaw()` invocation:


  Your raw query had an incorrect number of parameters. Expected: `1`, actual: `2`.
  code: 'P1016',
  clientVersion: '3.3.0',
  meta: { expected: 1, actual: 2 }
}
```

any suggestions ?
i'm not sure if this is a bug.

Comment: problem solved?

Comment: nope, still having this issue

Comment: the error is because query is not expecting a variable there. may be you try with string interpolation, and replace a block of query with a variable https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#using-variables have a look at this link. may be it helps

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
const interval = num + ' days';

${interval}::TEXT::INTERVAL
```

instead of **interval '${interval} day'**

This is work for me!

Answer (score 0):

didn't find an elegant solution in the prism documentation, I couldn't even find one, but there is a way that works...you can try this `${'variable'}`

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if the source for `interval` is safe (e.g. defined in your code elsewhere, *not* from user input) is to leverage `Prisma.raw` for that whole string, surrounding it with single quotes per usual:

```
const interval = 3;

const request = prisma.$queryRaw`
select count(id), 
       status,
       "createdAt"::date 
from "ProjectLog" 
where "projectId" = (select id 
                     from "Project" 
                     where slug = ${id}) 
  and "createdAt" > current_date - interval '${Prisma.raw(`${interval} day`}' 
group by "createdAt"::date, 
         status`;
```

Be careful with `$queryRaw` in combination with `Prisma.raw`, however.  The values placed in there aren't parameterized, but rather are included in the query text itself, so this code would be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks if you were getting `interval` from an unsafe source.